# Last date with time of the month

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

Need your help to conclude the query to fetch last date time of the sysdate month.

```
select to_char(last_day(sysdate),'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

it gives last date as expected, but I need time as `23:59:00` which is not possible thru above query.

Comment: It's almost always *easier* to compute an *exclusive* endpoint, if you're trying to define a range. E.g. use the first day of next month (easy to compute) and just use `<` rather than `<=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **TRUNC** on next day i.e. `SYSDATE + 1`, and then subtract `60` seconds i.e. `60/86400` to get the desired output.

```
SQL> SELECT to_char((trunc(last_day(sysdate)) +1) - 60/86400,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt
  2  FROM dual;

DT
--------------------
29-Feb-2016 23:59:00

SQL>
```

You could also use `interval '1' minute` or `interval '60' second` instead of `60/86400`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it for *display* for some reason you can hard-code the time into the format mask:

```
select to_char(last_day(sysdate), 'DD-Mon-YYYY "23:59:00"') from dual;
```

But you probably really want it as a date object, in which case you can add 23 hours and 59 minutes to the truncated (midnight) date, wchi is 1439 of the 1440 minutes in a day:

```
select to_char(trunc(last_day(sysdate)) + 1439/1440, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;
```

Or you can go to the next day and remove a minute, either with fractional days or with intervals:

```
select to_char(trunc(last_day(sysdate)) + interval '1' day - interval '1' minute,
  'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Generally if you're working with time periods you want to include up to 23:59:59, which you can also do with any of those methods, but as Damien_The_Unbeliever said in a comment, it's easier to compare against the start of the next period (e.g. `< add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1)`. It's easy to accidentally miss part of a day by not taking the time into account properly, particularly if you actually have a timestamp rather than a date.